# logarithmic rebinning of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resolution

I have a 1D ray containing data that looks like this (48000 points), spaced by one wavenumber (R = 1 cm-1). The shape of the x and y array is (48000, 1), I want to rebin both in a similar way

```
xarr=[50000,9999,9998,....,2000]
yarr=[0.1,0.02,0.8,0.5....0.1]
```

I wish to decrease the spatial resolution, lets say R= 10 cm-1), so I want ten times less points (4800), from 50000 to 2000. And do the same for the y array

**How to start?**

I try by taking the natural log of the wavelength scale, then re-bin this onto a new log of wavelength scale generate using np.linspace()

```
xi=np.log(xarr[0])
xf=np.log(xarr[-1])
xnew=np.linspace(xi, xf, num=4800)
```

now I need to recast the y array into this xnew array, I am thinking of using rebin, a 2D rebin, but not sure how to use this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to DROP 9 out of 10 values (decimation), or do you want to INTERPOLATE them (resample)?

Comment: I'd prefer to resample

Comment: I suggest you try both `scipy.signal.resample` and `scipy.signal.decimate`.  Resample uses an FFT, so it works best with periodic signals.  Decimate does a smoothing filter first, which is where it interpolates.

Comment: I edited my answer above to show that I want to rebin (average) my y array values into the newly binned x array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it seems to work!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

#irregular x and y arrays
yirr= np.random.randint(1,101,10)
xirr=np.arange(10)

nbins=5
bin_means, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(xirr,yirr, 'mean', bins=nbins)

yreg=bin_means # <== regularized yarr

xi=xirr[0]
xf=xirr[-1]
xreg=np.linspace(xi, xf, num=nbins)

print('yreg',yreg)
print('xreg',xreg) # <== regularized xarr
```

If anyone can find an improvement or see a problem with this, please post!
I'll try it on my logarithmically scaled data now

Answer (score 0):

import numpy as np

arr1=[2,3,65,3,5...,32,2]

series=np.array(arr1)

print(series[:3])

Comment: That's decimation.  That's a practical approach, if it meets the OP's needs.

Comment: not really, I'd like to rebin (average) my y array values into a new xarray (downsampled)

Comment: could using stats.binned_statistic_2d help?